# Creating a host record for an IP address to be used for SPF

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I would like to allow an email service to be a valid sender for my domain. This service has dedicated a single IP for my account.

Instead of:

```
v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 -all
```

Will the following behave the same assuming I have a host record corresponding to the IP address?

```
v=spf1 include:service.domain.com -all
```

**edited to correct -all syntax*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a preamble there's (almost) no point of using a spf if it is with a "~all". You shoud use "-all".

As for the "include" statement, it is used to "add" to your spf another existing spf record.

I.E. the spf record, if it exists, of the domain listed in the include will be evaluated as well as the remaining of your spf.

You can use the "a" syntax to evaluate a DNS name instead of an IPv4 address.

So you may use:

```
v=spf1 a:service.domain.com -all
```

Comment: +1 for the very correct objection to `~all`.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. _I feel pretty stupid about the ~all thing_

Answer (score 0):

the include: option will search for SPF records at the specified domain name.

I think you are looking for a: option like:

```
v=spf1 a:service.domain.com ~all
```

Also there are numerous online tools to verify your SPF records in a more human readable way.